# compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED Error android.widget.menu;

Tags: java, android, build, build.gradle, javac

I am having an issue during app build process. It's giving this error again and again.
I tried many time to clean, Rebuild and invalidate & restart but nothing is working.
I also changes sdk Versions and build versions but nothing seems to work for me.
Can you please let me know what is happening why this error is keep getting.

I researched all around the google and tried different solutions but no luck

**Here is Build Error Code**

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
F:\Selloz Application Data\Selloz App Source Code\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\market\selloz\databinding\MainMenuBinding.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
import android.widget.menu;
                     ^
  symbol:   class menu
  location: package android.widget
F:\Selloz Application Data\Selloz App Source Code\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\market\selloz\databinding\MainMenuBinding.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
  private final menu rootView;
                ^
  symbol:   class menu
  location: class MainMenuBinding
F:\Selloz Application Data\Selloz App Source Code\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\market\selloz\databinding\MainMenuBinding.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
  private MainMenuBinding(@NonNull menu rootView) {
                                   ^
  symbol:   class menu
  location: class MainMenuBinding
F:\Selloz Application Data\Selloz App Source Code\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\market\selloz\databinding\MainMenuBinding.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
  public menu getRoot() {
         ^
  symbol:   class menu
  location: class MainMenuBinding
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
4 errors

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libimagepipeline.so.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 42s
30 actionable tasks: 29 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

This is the **MainMenuBinding.java** that is opening after this error

```
// Generated by view binder compiler. Do not edit!
package com.market.selloz.databinding;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.menu;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding;
import com.market.selloz.R;
import java.lang.NullPointerException;
import java.lang.Override;

public final class MainMenuBinding implements ViewBinding {
  @NonNull
  private final menu rootView;

  private MainMenuBinding(@NonNull menu rootView) {
    this.rootView = rootView;
  }

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public menu getRoot() {
    return rootView;
  }

  @NonNull
  public static MainMenuBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater) {
    return inflate(inflater, null, false);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static MainMenuBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable ViewGroup parent, boolean attachToParent) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu, parent, false);
    if (attachToParent) {
      parent.addView(root);
    }
    return bind(root);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static MainMenuBinding bind(@NonNull View rootView) {
    if (rootView == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("rootView");
    }

    return new MainMenuBinding((menu) rootView);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is class "menu" in package "android.widget"? Check the javadocs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary

Comment: Hi, @pringi   I can't found any Menu Class in document but I had used Popup menu inside my app and that is working perfectly but from 2 days suddenly it started showing this error . i don't know what is wrong and what i have to do to resolve this issue .

Comment: Post Updated Please check again . thanks